# attach additional variable to ajax processing input type file

Tags: javascript

```
<input type='file' id='inpfile' accept='image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif' hidden>
```

I need to change `src` of `imgauth` but also need an aditional variable called `name`

```
$('#inpfile').change(function(){
    var name = $('#selauth').val(); // this is the additional variable
    var file_data = $('#inpfile').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('inpfile', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "authors-pro-img-from-disc.php",
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data, // this works
        //data: {form_data, 'name': name}, // this doesn't work
        success: function(data){
            $('#imgauth').attr('src', data);
        }
    });
});
```

**php side**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

So how can I attach `name` variable and send it to server, together with image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append name field the same way you did for the file:

```
var name = $('#selauth').val(); // this is the additional variable
var file_data = $('#inpfile').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('inpfile', file_data);
form_data.append('name', name); // <-------- append name
```

Then read in on the server as `$_POST['name']`.